# How to dynamically filter viewmodel of a Razor page in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filter, viewmodel, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a viewmodel that I send and render in a page. Now, I'd like to add an input control and when I type something there (and press a button, possibly), filter the viewmodel.

The data set is limited so I want to avoid a roundtrip to the server. Filtration can be carried out on the client.

In an Angular application, it's easy. I'm not sure how to do it in a proper way in MVC, though. Googling gave a too wide range of suggestions and also drowned in WPF and XAML references for viewmodel.

Suggestions?

Comment: Q: Could you give a brief code snippet describing how you'd do it in Angular?  Just to give us a better idea of exactly what you mean by "filtering"?  ALSO: Please bear in mind that Razor is more "server side" (like JSP, PHP or ASP); whereas Angular is more "client side" (hence the need to minimize "round trips").  Again - any kind of concrete example (preferably a code example) would be helpful.

Comment: Why not use an ajax query to pull the results post-load and store in a input auto complete. Otherwise just load the values in the view for the autocomplete if the dataset is limited. Chosen the jQuery library is pretty good for it

Comment: @paulsm4 I'd use *ng-for* on the bound model and change the "behind-model" filtered by an event fired while changing the input box with filtration string. Perhaps MVC isn't a good choice for on-client filtration.

Comment: @JacksonCollins I haven't touched jQuery for many years. In fact, I though it was dead and gone by now. Care to give me a hint on link that describes the approach? I've found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.2) but it's nothing about jQuery in there...

Comment: These days, "Angular" generally means "Angular 2 or higher" (e.g. Angular7). The "old version" is usually called "AngularJS".  `ng-for` is AngularJS, not Angular. I'm still guessing that what you mean by "filtering" really makes sense for the client side (like an Angular service ... or a jQuery XHR call).  And yes, jQuery is very definitely alive and well.  I'd go so far as to say that *every* front end developer should know at least some *basic* jQuery.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana There may be better libraries out there for it but depending on how much data you want to filter by jquery can do it pretty simple. If its just an array of string results then you can just use an ajax request to fetch the results and populate a dropdown and use the library Chosen.js to allow filtering on those results otherwise if you want to filter by more then just one value you could try creating an ajax datatable that you pass a filter and return a list of results and you can even use autocomplete on that too. Datatable ajax server-side processing are the key words for that

Comment: @JacksonCollins I'll ended up expanding my viewmodel by a search field, providing the collected filter information to the backend. Then, I do it all-server-side. Not happy about that but it seems the best fit for the situation. In the future, when I rebuild the whole shabang, I'll just expose the APIs and present it all in an SPA. (I tried SPA-way at first but got stuck on the authorization issues - and the software needs to be delivered soon so I went for "whatever works, if yet poorly", hehe.)

Comment: @DonkeyBanana Yeah it's not optimal but it's not terrible, if you have very limited data and it all comes through the view model you could just plug it into a datatable and let them filter through on the client side